# Проблема с отправкой и получением данных через curl (php)

Tags: php, curl

столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
1 скрипт достаёт из бд данные, и отправляет их на другой через curl методом POST,
при этом в обоих скриптах стоит var_dump, в скрипте который отправляет все данные нормально вар дампаются, а в скрипте который принимает вместо массива с кучей данных просто пишет Array (пустой массив).
Вот как это выглядит:
[image: Сверху вар дамп из файла который отправляет, снизу из файла куда отправляются эти данные]

Сверху вар дамп из файла который отправляет, снизу из файла куда отправляются эти данные
Вот код файла который отправляет данные:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '600000');
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'shop');

mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

$order = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($link,"SELECT shipping_firstname AS firstname, shipping_lastname AS lastname, email, telephone, custom_field, shipping_address_1 AS address, shipping_postcode, shipping_city, shipping_method, payment_method, comment FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = 338"), MYSQLI_ASSOC)[0];
$orderProducts = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT op.order_id, op.name, op.quantity, op.price, op.total, IF(oo.nomenclature_id IS NOT NULL, oo.nomenclature_id, p.nomenclature_id) AS nomenclature_id, IF(oo.characteristic_id IS NOT NULL, oo.characteristic_id, p.characteristic_id) AS characteristic_id FROM oc_order_product AS op INNER JOIN oc_product AS p ON p.product_id = op.product_id LEFT JOIN oc_order_option AS oo ON op.order_product_id = oo.order_product_id WHERE op.order_id = 338"), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$send = array(
    'order' => $order,
    'orderProducts' => $orderProducts
);
var_dump($send);
echo '<br><br>';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://localhost/test/printCheck.php";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

А вот код файла который получает данные:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', '600000');


var_dump($_POST);


?>
```

Подскажите в чём проблема, а то я себе уже весь мозг сломал, перелопатив всю документацию по curl)

Comment: json_encode($send) попроуй так

Comment: данные приходят, но все данные (вся json строка) это ключ элемента массива, с пустым значением [вот в таком виде](http://prntscr.com/ktjurt)

Answer (score -1):

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($send));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

попробуй так

Comment: так он вообще ничего не возвращает(

Comment: $result = curl_exec($curl);

Comment: print_r($result);

Comment: я не настолько тупой), разумеется я вывел результат, но там пусто

Comment: заметил 1 интересную вещь, если отправлять одномерный массив, всё корректно работает, а если 1 из элеметнов массива содержит в себе другой массив всё идёт через жопу

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
$send = array(
    'order' => json_encode($order),
    'orderProducts' => json_encode($orderProducts)
);
```

curl почему то работает только с одномерными массивами